# jquery ui slider

Tags: jquery, ui

Как вывести значения с ползунков  в `alert()` при нажатии кнопки? Т.е. по сути мне нужны установленные на ползунках значения, чтобы потом отправить их `ajax`-ом в `php` скрипт.

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 1000,
        max: 45000,
        values: [1000, 45000],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + "руб." + ui.values[1] + "руб.");
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
        "руб." + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) + "руб.");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 1000,
        max: 45000,
        values: [1000, 45000],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.values[0]+" "+ui.values[1])
            $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + "руб." + ui.values[1] + "руб.");
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
        "руб." + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) + "руб.");
});
```

но там на каждый чих будет меняться и отправлятся сумма